# Cordova App launching Google App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After using the below code. App is launching the native android map showing the app with passed lat and long value.but my problem is after clicking on the nav  option the 'from' is blank but 'to'  should be coming as my passed value. But it is coming as blank value.

```
window.location = 'geo:40.765819,-73.975866'
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think Cordova supports using magnet links

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Cordova plugins, then I would suggest taking a look at the [Launch Navigator plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator).

It allows you to do exactly what you want, but also allows you to launch other supported apps and even allows you to prompt the user with a list of applications to choose from.

There is an [example in the documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#advanced-usage), showing how you can open a specific application, like Google Maps. For your convenience, I have also posted it below.

```
launchnavigator.isAppAvailable(launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS, function(isAvailable) {
    var app;

    if(isAvailable) {
        app = launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS;
    } else {
        console.log("Google Maps not available - falling back to user selection");
        app = launchnavigator.APP.USER_SELECT;
    }

    launchnavigator.navigate([40.765819, -73.975866], {
        app: app
    });
});
```

In this piece of code, the user will still be given a choice to pick another app, if Google Maps is not available.

There is also an AngularJS wrapper available for this called ngCordova, installation instructions are [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) and documentation about the wrapper for the Launch Navigator plugin can be found [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/launchNavigator/).